# Keep a live websocket when app is in terminated ( kill ) state

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, websocket, push-notification

I am using [websocket](https://github.com/tidwall/SwiftWebSocket) with Swift 2 to maintain some data between app and server. This websocket works fine in foreground and background state, but when I terminate ( kill ) app then websocket connection breaks. When coming again to the app it will start working again.

**Notes:**

- All background, VOIP, and other permissions are given.
- Generally, websocket don't work in the background, I have figured out
  a solution to keep working in background state and when the device is
  locked.
- Tried silent push notification as well, which invokes method for
  websocket connection, silent push notification happens but the method
  works only when going back to the application.

So, any idea and suggestion appreciated about how to keep a live websocket when an app is in terminated ( kill ) state?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're never going to have a handler for that, using silent push, only when the app becomes active again it will be processed. I really can´t see a way of doing that.

Comment: @Brduca - I am not getting any handler for this and also silent push notification works only when i am going back to application. can anyone know any other options ?

Comment: Hasya, that's what I'm telling you. It's not possible.

Comment: Anyone has idea to invoke specific method with use of silent pushnotification or pushkit ?

Comment: Hello Hasya,

Could you please let me know how you kept websocket alive while app is in background??

Comment: Hello Varun, I have used https://github.com/tidwall/SwiftWebSocket. While app gets terminated websocket goes off otherwise that works fine in foreground and background mode. In Background you cant process UI things but code related things you can handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. When the user terminates the app everything goes with it, if that wasn't the case then users would have no way to stop apps doing strange things (other than to restart the whole device).

Additionally you should not try exotic things to get around system restrictions as this will (eventually) lead to app rejection of you release to the store and / or users who are unhappy with battery life when your app is running.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wain, i need to know 1 thing from you, For example app is in kill state and app getting push notification as "Incoming call", after 1 minute again getting another push notification as "Missed call", still i havnt touched any notification, so is it possible when "Missed call" notification comes in notification tray ( bar ) then can we clear / remove "Incoming call" push notification? ( user havn't touched anything yet. )

Comment: No, there is not way to edit that list, iOS deals with that for you (in relation to user interaction)

Comment: Wain, How that happens with Skype iOS app ? that happens with Skype.your help would be great for me.

Comment: What have you observed with Skype? My Skype notifications don't get removed automatically when I open the app...

Comment: Incoming call notification arrived, when call is not received then missed call notification coming, that time incoming call notification is getting removed. ( User has not touched notification yet ) still such thing is happening, any idea for same ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement the behaviour you are looking for with a push notification with content available, which gives you some time awake to download content in the background (more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)), in order to do this your payload should be structured like,

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1
    },
    "data-id" : 1234
}
```

Then implement the following method to download the content, or in your case do something with your web socket

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

This method should only be use to update some state in your app or download some data, Apple does not recommend using this to keep your socket always alive, and i'm sure will eventually reject your app if you use this to keep your socket always alive.

Comment: I know this and already implemented, silent push notification doesn't help to keep web socket alive. but this works only when going back to application from terminated state. well thanks a lot Francisco.